# Использование метода PUT в HTML-форме

Tags: java, html, http, form, servlet

Прохожу курс по серветам в java и дело в том, что атрибут формы method, принимает только 2 значения -> GET and POST. Тогда возникает вопрос, как передать сервлету сигнал о том что пришла форма с методом PUT? Так как сервлеты в java имеют метод doPut() в том числе, логично что должен быть способ как-то сообщить в форме, что пришла форма и ее нужно обработать методом doPut(). Варианты со скрытым полем в input теге, знаю, но приходится использовать дополнительные условия, а хотелоссь бы как правельно, сделать?

Comment: TopJava, наверное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

обычно отправка запроса, это проблема клиентской части =) Ваше дело написать реализацию метода.

Но в частности:

На сайтах, `html` `form` отправляет только get и post остальные отправляются например через `javascript`  или `jquery`

Пример `jquery`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script.cgi',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

дальше эта функция вешается на `html` элемент и при клике на него, будет отправлен `delete` запрос

Если клиентская часть не сайт, а допустим `android` приложение, то там средствами `android` передается нужный метод.

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример их использования: http://zetcode.com/articles/jsgridservlet/

А так-то, на [JGuru](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=236578) пишут что только в подобных случаях есть смысл использовать `doPut()`:

```
->GET /file.dat HTTP/1.1

<-HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

->PUT /file.dat HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello!

<-HTTP/1.1 200 OK

->GET /file.dat HTTP/1.1

<-HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello!
```